# How can I set up multiple local wordpress sites using wordpress from the repo?

Tags: apache2, wordpress

I want to set up multiple local Wordpress sites for test purposes. I tried the following instructions:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WordPress
- https://wiki.debian.org/WordPress#An_alternate_installation_method

I tried to make sure that all permissions are right, but all I get when I try to open the URL returned by the `setup-mysql` script is a 403 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using the `/srv/www` directory caused problems for some reason.  The following procedure eventually did the trick (on Ubuntu 14.04):

**Install packages**

```
sudo apt-get install wordpress mysql-server
```

(`mysql-server` is not automatically installed as a dependency of `wordpress`, so it has to be installed explicitly.)

**Set up virtual host**

Say I want to access one local wordpress site via `http://xyz/`. I create the file
`/etc/apache2/sites-available/xyz.conf`
with the following content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName xyz
        UseCanonicalName Off
        VirtualDocumentRoot /usr/share/wordpress
        Options All

        # wp-content in /var/www/wp-content/$0
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^/wp-content/(.*)$ /var/www/wp-content/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

(This is almost identical with [what the Debian Wiki suggests](https://wiki.debian.org/WordPress#An_alternate_installation_method), but with an added `ServerName` and `/srv/www` replaced by `/var/www`.)

Now I add an entry in `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.1.2   xyz
```

(the last `2` could be replaced with a different number).

Now I enable the virtual host and some required modules:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2enmod vhost_alias
sudo a2ensite xyz
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Set up Wordpress**

The `wordpress` package comes with a script to set up a Wordpress instance and a dedicated database.  However, it does so at `/srv/www`, which did not work for me.  So I unpacked the script...

```
gzip -dc < /usr/share/doc/wordpress/examples/setup-mysql.gz > setup-mysql
```

and replaced `/srv/www` with `/var/www`:

```
sed -i 's/\/srv\/www/\/var\/www/g' setup-mysql
```

Now, I can run the modified script to set up the Wordpress instance:

```
sudo bash setup-mysql -n xyz_db xyz
```

where the first `xyz_db` will become the database name and `xyz` the URL and directory name. The latter should match the URL that was set up above, the database could be named anything else, but it's sensible to give it a name that makes clear it's associated with the URL.

Now the URL can be opened in the browser to start working with the Wordpress instance.